# how to compile Dlib on mac?

Tags: macos, cmake, dlib

I am trying to build dlib19.4 I run the following commands on terminal

```
cd examples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

but I get these errors on below after a while

> /usr/local/include/dlib/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.h:11:2: error: 
>         "DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT is defined so you can't use the GUI code. Turn
>         DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT off if you want to use it."
>   (#error "DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT is defined so you can't use the GUI code.  T...
>
> /usr/local/include/dlib/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.h:12:2: error: "Also make
>         sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system"
>   (#error "Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system"

how can I overcome this problem?